# Logstash duplicate data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Can someone help me with logstash. I want to sync PostgreSQL with elastic the problem is the current setting duplicate data in es. I know creating a field "id" can help but still logstash recreate the whole index.

SQL

```
SELECT id, title, description, type,"updatedAt" FROM public.videos WHERE ("updatedAt" > :sql_last_value AND "updatedAt" < NOW())
```

```
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/postgresql-jdbc.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://{POSTGRES_URL}"
    jdbc_user => "${POSTGRES_USERNAME}"
    jdbc_password => "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "updatedAt"
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    use_column_value => true
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement_filepath => "/usr/share/logstash/sql/video.sql"
    tags => "video"
  }

output {
  if "video" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["${ES_HOSTS}"]
      index => "video"
      # document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
      user => "${ES_USER}"
      password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
      cacert => '/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt'
      doc_as_upsert => true
    }
  }
}
```

Settings from offical documentation for mysql

```js
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "<path>/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://<MySQL host>:3306/es_db"
    jdbc_user => <my username>
    jdbc_password => <my password>
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "unix_ts_in_secs"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM es_table WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) > :sql_last_value AND modification_time < NOW()) ORDER BY modification_time ASC"
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the `output` section of your config?

Comment: I think the problem is in SQL

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, it really depends on where you send the data and which id you give each document.

Comment: I have found the problem. Column updatedAt is automatically created and I do not know why but logstash do not treat it as value. I created a new column updated with the last update timestamp and it works. I think it is some kind of bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your input section, you need to make sure that your `tracking_column` is actually a real field that can be tracked:

```
tracking_column => "updatedAt"
```

Your output section should look like this instead. It is important to properly set the `document_id` and `[@metadata][_id]` has no value in random value, hence the duplicates.

```
elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["${ES_HOSTS}"]
  index => "video"
  document_id => "%{id}"                   <---- change this line
  user => "${ES_USER}"
  password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
  cacert => '/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt'
}
```

Comment: Like I said it will solve a problem with duplication but still logstash fetch this same data from postgres over and over again rebuilding index

Comment: You had two problems, one was the tracking column (which is now clear from your comment, but wasn't from your initial question) and the other was the output that was not configured properly.